# How to move to the next image in the horizontal ScrollView in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am using `gallery` to add the images and use the horizontal `ScrollView` for scrolling the images of the gallery. Now the problem is, if I flip the first image then it does not go to next image, it displays improperly.

Answer (score 1):

@ram  try this code for horizontalscrollview :

HorizontalScrollView sView = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01);
sView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
sView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);

and use this xml  scrollview.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                >
            </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try following [example](http://code.google.com/p/deezapps-widgets/source/browse/#svn/trunk/res).